# NodeJs: convert array of objects to a big object

Tags: node.js, influxdb

i want to write points to InfluxDB. Refer to https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/introduction/

The fields of the point are array of objects:

```
[ { water: 8.12 }, { temp: 22.05 }, { humid: 60.04 } ]
```

how can this array be converted to an object of the format

```
 { water: 8.12 ,  temp: 22.05 ,  humid: 60.04 }
```

as required by this package https://github.com/vicanso/influxdb-nodejs ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical task for `Array.reduce`. Check out [docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=control) to learn more.

Here is how it can be applied to your question:

```
const data = [ { water: 8.12 }, { temp: 22.05 }, { humid: 60.04 } ];
const obj = data.reduce((memo, value) => Object.assign(memo, value), {});
```

In short:

1. It takes empty object `{}` as a starting point
2. It assigns each object from array (`value` variable) to a starting point (`memo` variable)
3. In the end there is an object composed from array

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With ES6, you could use **destructuring**:

```js
let arr = [ { water: 8.12 }, { temp: 22.05 }, { humid: 60.04 } ],
    [{water}, {temp}, {humid}] = arr,
    obj = {water, temp, humid};
    
console.log(obj);
```